# Will nesting tds in an inline div cause rendering issues?

Tags: html, css

On desktop I set my divs to display as table cells but change them to inline-blocks on mobile. I choose to use table cells on desktop so that all side-by-side blocks are the same height regardless of the height of their content. I'd like to use this same table cell method for the interval of window size between mobile and desktop but want to display two blocks side-by-side with a divider (instead of four side-by-side blocks with three dividers). I was wondering whether placing an div around each pair of "responsiveelements" and setting each div to inline for desktop would cause the page to render differently than if they weren't present. If I'm not mistaken, I should be able to accomplish what I intend to if this wouldn't cause issues.

```css
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .responsiveelement {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 0 20px !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
  .responsivetable {
    display: block !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
  .celldivider {
    display: none;
  }
}

.celldivider {
  display: table-cell;
}

.responsiveelement {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 23.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table2">
    <div class="responsiveelement"></div>
    <div class="celldivider"></div>
    <div class="responsiveelement"></div>
  </div>
    <div class="celldivider middle"></div>
  <div class="table2">
    <div class="responsiveelement"></div>
    <div class="celldivider"></div>
    <div class="responsiveelement"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly then this should work:

HTML

```
<div>
 <div class='mobile_tr'> 
 <div class='td'>Text</div>
 <div class='td'>Text</div>
 </div>
 <div class='mobile_tr'>
 <div class='td'>Text</div>
 <div class='td'>Text</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  display: table
}

.mobile_tr {
  display: inline-block;
}

.td {
  display: table-cell;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .mobile_tr {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Essentially you group all your "cells" by 2 and you render the wrap as an `inline-block` element which allows for the "cells" to concatenate in a single row. When the device is mobile the wrap is rendered as a block bringing the next wrap to a newline. Unfortunately there is no CSS only way of doing this that I know of.

Edit: So in short, no :P you are on the right track. :D

Comment: Thanks for your help! It seems the easiest solution to my problem is setting the "table2" divs to display:contents.